# wxpython webview not loading certain page

Tags: webview, wxpython, chromium-embedded

I have followed a few different tutorials on wxpython's webview (specifically utilizing html2) but have not been able to load this page https://openmct-demo.herokuapp.com. I have been able use an example with Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/wxpython.py to render the page successfully but I cannot get this solution to work with wxasync. So any help with either path (html2 to render page or cef with wxasync) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: I am using the following packages on Ubuntu 18.04.
Python 3.6.8 64bit
CEF Python v66.0
wxPython 4.0.6 gtk2 (phoenix)
wxWidgets 3.0.5

Comment: The website loads fine in a html2.WebView on OSX, but it also fails to get past the splash image on Windows. Interestingly it does the same thing on Windows in IE 11, but does succeed in Edge. I suspect that the site is doing something advanced or browser-specific in its JavaScript, and is not robust enough to fall back to something else when running in a less capable JS engine.